# Dual isogeny of $F$ if $[n]-[m]F=0$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I was trying to solve the following exercise of elliptic curves:

**Let $F$ be an isogeny such that there exists $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $[n]-[m]F=[0]$, then $F=\hat{F}$, where $\hat{F}$ is the dual isogeny.**

At first sight it looks a trivial exercise, but I got stuck at the last part. This is my attempt:

Taking dual isogenies:
$$[n]-\widehat{F}[m]=\widehat{[n]}-\widehat{F}\widehat{[m]}=\widehat{[n]-[m]F}=\widehat{[0]}=[0]=[n]-[m]F$$
Here I only used basic properties of isogenies. Thus we have $\widehat{F}[m]=[m]F$. How am I supposed to show that $F=\widehat{F}$ from here? I guess that the exercise is meant to be solved applying elementary properties of rational maps and dual isogenies, but I don't see what I'm missing.

Any hints or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the meaning of $[n]=[m]F$ is. One is an endomorphism the other is an isogeny. If it means that $F$ is an endomorphism then 

 $\widehat{F}[m]=[m]F$ gives $\widehat{F}[m]=F[m]$ so that $\widehat{F}-F$ has infinite kernel, it must be $0$.

Comment: @reuns yes sorry, it is also an endomorphism. I mean, it is an isogeny from an elliptic curve to itself, thanks.